# How to record audio running out of iphone speakers?

Tags: ios, audio, record, audio-recording

Hey, I'm a new developer in Objective C. I'm trying to record the audio running out of iPhone speakers. I can capture the audio by mouth speaker and record it. But I cannot record the audio producing from my iPhone. Please help me.

Comment: I guess there must be some way to record. Because there are call record applications which records voice from your mic and speaker as well.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to directly capture from the "audio bus".  You can either capture the audio via the internal microphone or headset microphone, but that's it.  If you are rendering the audio, you could obviously also write that audio out to a file as well at the same time.  That's pretty much your only option.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you only get a handle on the audio generated by your process. There is no way to get the audio generated by the rest of the system.

Comment: any comment on how to record the audio generated by the process?

Comment: I don't think there is even a way to do this.  Apologies for my answer being misleading.